# Getting User Role from Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I created a simple Asp.net web application project and published it on Azure using Azure Web App service, I have also set up the authentication but I did it from Azure. In Azure web app you get the option to set authentication using azure Ad.

And in my app i simply gave a logout button with link mydomain/.auth/logout and it is working fine. In my app there is  no code for any authentication.

Is there a way through which i can get the role of the user (I have set 2 roles in my azure app registration manifest and have also assigned these roles to the users) which logged-in in my app. I have searched but i am not able to find it. I was able to do it when i set the authentication process through code by using owin and open-id-connect but i don't want to do it that way. Is there some way i could do it without writing the authentication code in my app?

Comment: Those should be there in the id token if you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are two ways to get the role of logged-in user But I'm not sure whether they can be used in your scenario.

1. As juunas said, you can get the information from the `id_token`. I test it, you can decode the `id_token` and get the role:

[image]

2. If you know the Principal Dispaly Name of that user, you can get the role via AAD Powershell, here is my scripts and result:

```html
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "<the ObjectId of that SP>"| % {    
      $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
      $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }
      Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | Select ResourceDisplayName, PrincipalDisplayName,  Id | Where-Object {$_.PrincipalDisplayName -eq "yangsa666@outlook.com" } | % {  $_ | Add-Member "AppRoleDisplayName" $appRoles[$_.Id] -Passthru
      }
    }
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried running it in powershell it says The term 'Get-AzureADServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Hi,@RahulGupta . Did install [Azure AD Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module) ?

Comment: :) It's working but when i am putting object id it says resource does not exist , in object id i am putting the object id which we get when we register app in azure ad .....I tried with both object ID and App Id

Comment: Probably wrong object id. You need to find the service principal object id. That's the "App in local directory" / enterprise application.

Comment: It will not work from code  because to use this you need to first connect to AzureAd but for me authentication is not being done through code